# Laravel Vue Project gets blank white page on initial run only on production, solved with hard refresh. How can I prevent this?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, vue.js, laravel-mix, laravel-forge

I'm building a web app using Laravel 8.6, Vue 3.2, and hosting on AWS with Laravel Forge. Everything works fine locally and on staging. However, when I deploy the app to production, some people initially see a blank white screen. They don't see any errors in the console. This problem is fixed with a hard refresh on the browser. However, when I try to replicate this issue locally, I can't replicate it.

The only real difference between local and staging and production is that on production, I'm running "npm run prod", which runs "npx mix --production".

Could this be an error in the server configuration? Any idea how to solve?

I appreciate any comments or suggestions!

Comment: Is Staging and Production on AWS + Forge? If that is the case and Staging NEVER has this issue, then it could be a misconfiguration on Production (but maybe not Mix). I am thinking it is more of a "accessing files slowly" thing than a misconfiguration. Can you ask your clients to watch the `network` tab instead of `console` and see how the assets connections resolve (order and time)?

Comment: Hi Matias, yes, both staging and production are on AWS + Forge. Our clients actually never see staging and I haven't been able to replicate this issue personally. You bring up an interesting point regarding asset connections. I've tried in Slow 3G and while it is slow and there is a white screen for a while, it eventually does load after 10 seconds.

Comment: It is very rough to reproduce then... how were your clients able to reproduce it the first time? Like, if you try again with Slow 3G but on incognito, do you still have everything loaded? Can you share what type of linking are you using on the HTML? Maybe you can `defer` any of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer.

The problem was that Laravel Mix was adding a hash to app.js, but NOT adding it to the chunked bundles.

I needed to change up the `webpack.mix.js` file and add the chunkhash to the output. This ensured that the chunked files weren't brought in `from disk cache`.

For example:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    ...
    output: {
        chunkFilename: '[name].js?[chunkhash]',
    }
})
```

Note that I added the `?[chunkhash]` after the filename.

Here was my inspiration: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/laravel-vue-files-requiring-hard-refresh-even-when-caching-implemented

Answer (score 0):

Could be related to the users in production having a cached copy of your assets, if not already, can you add to your webpack.mix.js file:

```
if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

To ensure that users are getting a fresh copy of your assets when you deploy to production (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting )

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not help :(